# If matter was compressed at big bang was time more and more compressed too in the past for us now (opposite expansion for time going in the past)?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, time-dilation, big-bang

If everything was smaller or compress in the past, did this compress time?
In the foundation of Big bang theory, all is expanding now, galaxies expand space between. Then they must had been closer or compress in the past. This compress space and time.
Did time run slower and slower in the past? (More and more compress)
Observer in each reference frame will only see futur expansion of space time since they follow time. Time relative to our frame would be compress compare to us, as space. Each frame being smaller than the previous. All frame having still one unit, unless compare externally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time dilation at the Big Bang](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119441/)

Comment: See also [Big bang and time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1192/).

Comment: Thank you John, it in the same view, but I mean a continuous contraction of time up to big bang, similar to space one

Comment: The FLRW metric has a scale factor only on its spatial components. Sure you can reexpress it as a conformal transformation of some Minkowski metric, but the zeroth parameter will not be the cosmological time.